# Purpose of .rerunning

Tags: unix

I have come across a shell script where below mentioned scripts are defined -

```
test -f .rerunning
touch .rerunning
```

Please let me know the purpose of the above mentioned unix commands and the difference between them?

Comment: Do the lines appear as you have posted it? or was it something like `test -f .rerunning && touch .rerunning`?

Comment: Yes || is there.

test -f .rerunning || {
touch .rerunning


#Some code here

}

echo Another instance is currently running. Aborting.
exit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `test` is another way of calling an `if` statement.

Hence,

```
test -f .rerunning
```

check if the file `.rerunning` exists or not.

The line

```
touch .rerunning
```

updates the last edition time of the file `.rerunning`. If it does not exist, it is created.

As [Sylvain Defresne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809021/purpose-of-rerunning#comment24228232_16809051) and [Shawn Chin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809021/purpose-of-rerunning#comment24228284_16809021) indicate, having one line after the other without any `&&` or `||` does not make really sense.

---

Update from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809021/purpose-of-rerunning/16809051?noredirect=1#comment24228511_16809051):

> Yes || is there. `test -f .rerunning || { touch .rerunning #Some code
>   here } echo Another instance is currently running. Aborting. exit 1`
>   Are you saying there is .rerunning file ?

As it is a condition

```
A || B
```

If A true -> don't have to analyze B. If A false -> check B.

Hence, it tests if the file `.rerunning` exists. If it does, nothing is done. If it does not, it touches it, performs *some code*.

**To sum up**, the main idea must be to have a lock file to avoid multiple executions of a program.

Comment: There is no `&&` or `||` or anything else in the code fragment from the OP, so this will just test if the file is present and then inconditionally create it. Your explanation would be for `test -f .rerunning && touch .rerunning`.

Comment: Yes || is there.

test -f .rerunning || {
touch .rerunning


#Some code here

}

echo Another instance is currently running. Aborting.
exit 1


Are you saying there is .rerunning file ?